# Custom field value not saving in quickbooks using quickbooks-ruby GEM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, quickbooks

I am creating and saving custom field in invoice using the below code:

```
custom_field = Quickbooks::Model::CustomField.new
custom_field.name = "LFI Invoice #"
custom_field.type = "StringType"
custom_field.string_value = "LFI12345678"
invoice = Quickbooks::Model::Invoice.new
invoice.custom_fields = [custom_field]
```

so before saving the invoice object json is as below while debugging:

```
{
    "line_items": [
        {
            "amount": "5.99",
            "description": "Plush Baby Doll",
            "detail_type": "SalesItemLineDetail",
            "sales_line_item_detail": {
                "unit_price": "5.99",
                "quantity": 1,
                "item_ref": {
                    "value": "36"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "custom_fields": [
        {
            "name": "LFI Invoice #",
            "type": "StringType",
            "string_value": "LFI123456"
        }
    ],
    "customer_ref": {
        "value": "95"
    },
    "txn_date": "2015-02-05",
    "doc_number": ""
}
```

but after invoice creation it gives me empty custom field,when i query invoice in API explorer, it gives me below json of custom field part:

```
"CustomField": [
{
"DefinitionId": "1",
"Name": "LFI Invoice #",
"Type": "StringType"
}
],
```

Any suggestion what's the issue

Comment: looks for errors, `invoice.errors.messages`

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0300_developer_guides/custom_fields

You have to specify these fields to set a custom field value:

- DefinitionId (definition_id)
- Name (name)
- Type (type)
- StringValue (string_value)

You're not specifying the `definition_id` field.

Comment: Thanks keith , I got it as i was missing definition_id field.